# Does HttpClient adds any prefix to a JSON response?

Tags: java, json, gson, httpclient

I am using Apache HTTPClient 4.5.2 in the following code to fetch the JSON content.

Surprisingly a "?" gets prefixed in the body leading to a malformed JSON.

Code Below:

```
public class URLDataReader {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

         URLDataReader obj = new URLDataReader();
         String eventsURL = "http://api.511.org/traffic/events/?api_key=<my-personal-api-key>&format=json";

         String jsonText = null;
         try {
             jsonText = obj.readURLContent(eventsURL, true);
         } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
             System.out.print("Exception in Reading Data from the URL");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         if (jsonText != null) {
             System.out.println("Read JSON Content from URL :" + jsonText + "\n\n\n");
             Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
             EventQueryResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonText, EventQueryResponse.class);
             System.out.println("JSON read into Java Object:" + response.toString());
         }
     }

     public String readURLContent(String urlToRead, boolean useProxy) throws java.lang.Exception {

         String targetHost = new URL(urlToRead).getHost();

         String inputLine = null;
         StringBuffer result = null;

         String responseJsonBody = null;

         if (useProxy) {
             CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
             credsProvider.setCredentials(
                 new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
                 new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));

             CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
             HttpHost target = new HttpHost(targetHost, 80);
             HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);

             RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();

             System.out.println("URL Path:" + new URL(urlToRead).getFile());

             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(new URL(urlToRead).getFile());
             httpget.setConfig(config);
             CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget);


             responseJsonBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

             response.close();
             httpclient.close();

         } else {
             System.out.println("Not Implemented Yet!!");
         }

         return responseJsonBody;



     }

     private static String proxyUsername = "username";
     private static String proxyPassword = "password";
     private static String proxyHost = "proxy.host.com";
     private static int proxyPort = 80;

 }
```

The output I get is

```
URL Path:/traffic/events/?api_key=<my-personal-ap-key>&format=json
Read JSON Content from URL :?{"events":[{"url":"/traffic/events/511.org/23765","jurisdiction_url":"http://api.511.org/jurisdictions/511.org/","id":"511.org/23765","status":"ACTIVE","headline":"Caltrans : Long-term construction on CA-128 Eastbound and Westbound between Lower Chiles Valley Rd (Napa) and Berryessa Knoxville Rd (Napa). Alternate lanes closed. Expect delays.","event_type":"CONSTRUCTION","severity":"UNKNOWN","created":"2016-08-05T20:20Z","updated":"2016-08-07T17:28Z","geography":{"type":"Point","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}},"coordinates":[-122.296272,38.503876]},"roads":[{"name":"CA-128 E","from":"Lower Chiles Valley Rd","to":"Berryessa Knoxville Rd","state":"Open"}],"schedule":{"intervals":["2016-08-05T20:20Z/2016-10-01T06:55Z"]}},{"url":"/traffic/events/511.org/24826","jurisdiction_url":"http://api.511.org/jurisdictions/511.org/","id":"511.org/24826","status":"ACTIVE","headline":"CHP : Obstruction on I-580 Eastbound west of Marina Bay Pky (Richmond). Center lanes blocked. Expect delays.","event_type":"INCIDENT","severity":"UNKNOWN","created":"2016-08-08T12:00Z","updated":"2016-08-08T12:01Z","geography":{"type":"Point","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}},"coordinates":[-122.353792,37.921656]},"roads":[{"name":"I-580 E","from":"Marina Bay Pky","state":"Open"}],"schedule":{"intervals":["2016-08-08T12:00Z/"]}}],"pagination":{"offset":0},"meta":{"url":"/traffic/events/?api_key=65ce84c9-e5c4-43bf-ac16-a672e0b9266f&format=json","up_url":"/","version":"v1"}}
```

Not sure where the "?" is coming from at the beginning of the JSON response.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you use `curl` to access the same URL?

Comment: The correct JSON is displayed when I access the same URL using a browser.

Comment: The correct JSON is also displayed when accessed using curl:


`curl --compressed -x "http://username:password@proxy.host.com:80" "api.511.org/traffic/events/?api_key=<my-personal-key>&format=json"`


Output:

`{"events":[...],"pagination":{"offset":0},"meta":{"url":"/traffic/events/?api_key=65ce84c9-e5c4-43bf-ac16-a672e0b9266f&format=json","up_url":"/","version":"v1"}}`